# How to check if a TextView contains Strings from an Array?

Tags: java, android, textview

So, let's say I have an Array:

```
String Array[] = {"Dog goes woof", "Cat goes meow", "Cow goes moo", "Etc..."};
```

And I have a Button and a TextView connected so that when the button is pressed I can say for example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     TextView.setText(Array[1]);
}
```

Which will then fill the TextView with "Cat goes meow". But I now want the button to decided what should fill the TextView based on what's already there. So let's say I have Array[0] displayed in the TextView, so that it says "Dog goes woof". I then want an if-test that recognizes that Array[0] is displayed, and then changes it to, say, Array[2]. And if Array[2] is displayed, it will then change it to Array[1], and so on.

I am having a bit of issues on how I should set up this if-test, and how I should phrase it so that it recognizes what it is I am looking for in the TextView. And I do want to look for Array[X] or Array[Y] and not the strings themselves like "Dog goes woof". Basically something that says (warning: poor seudo-code ahead):

```
if TextView contains Array[X]
then TextView.setText(Array[Y])
else if TextView contains Array[Y]
then TextView.setText(Array[Z])
else TextView.setText(Array[X])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I easily understood your requirement and here's what you need:

```
    final Button yourButton= findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID);
    final String Array[] = {"Dog goes woof", "Cat goes meow", "Cow goes moo", "Etc..."};
    final TextView yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewID);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = 0;
            if(textView.getText() == null)
            {
                textView.setText(Array[1]); // initial value
            }
            else{
                for(int i=0;i<Array.length;i++){
                  if(Objects.equals(textView.getText(),Array[i])){
                    position=i; //got the selected position
                    break;
                  }
                }
                if(position<Array.length-1){
                    textView.setText(Array[position+1]); 

                }
                else{
                    textView.setText(Array[position-1]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This will check whether there is an initial value and in case of one then it will check for the selected position and if the position is less than the last item then it will increment one and if the last item is selected it will decrement one.
I've tested it and it's working, still something feel free to ask.

Comment: You may also not want to use this much code in an `onClickListener` then you can put this code in a method and call this method in the `onClick`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. While I did not want an increasing system like you submitted, you did however give me the answer I needed in how I needed to phrase the questioning to find what the TextView contained. The Objects.equals() part. I need to have a more manual system in place, but your answer gave me the solution I needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @PQuix Glad, it helped, even I do not recommend to use this much code in an `OnClick` that's why I commented to use a method instead.